# PHP Replace text inside curly brackets

Tags: php, regex

How can I replace letters only (a-zA-z) inside curly brackets?  I am currently using this, but it replaces numbers as well.

```
/{{([^}]+)}}/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do sample input strings look like and what is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Post your solution so that OP could accept it.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Pranav C Balan in a comment, you need to specify that you want alpha characters only in your regex, so:

```
/{{([a-zA-Z]+)}}/
```

Should do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex

```
/{{([a-zA-Z]+)}}/
```

**[Explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/lW3pL2/1)**

```
{{([a-zA-Z]+)}}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vo7-TX-C62OALkLt)**